Tauri.conf.json Changed icons. productName, and title and now get errors when trying to start up Tauri application
I am very new to Tauri so I'm not sure why I'm getting this problem. All I did was try and change the icons into my own icon that I made (and I made sure that the icons I made where the sizes of the default Tauri ones) and then I tried to change the name of my project. After I did those things I got these errors in the console:
`ERROR: tauri.conf.json has unknown property package +0ms
ERROR: tauri.conf.json > tauri has unknown property allowlist +0ms
ERROR: tauri.conf.json > tauri > security > csp should be string +1ms
ERROR: tauri.conf.json > tauri > window has unknown property 0 +0ms
ERROR: tauri.conf.json > tauri > window should have required property 'title' +0ms
PS C:\Users\Migru\Documents\EVIL_EXPIREMENTS\File Conversion TEST 1\converter-app>
I tried to change it back to the defaults and I still got these same exact errors.`
I don't know much about the differences in each of the Tauri versions but I did npm run tauri --version and it said that I was on 10.8.1. I would deeply appreciate if someone would help me figure out what is wrong. I've been working on this project for so long and I really don't want to loose it. Here is my tauri.conf.json:
`        {
      "build": {
        "beforeDevCommand": "npm run dev",
        "beforeBuildCommand": "npm run build",
        "devPath": "http://localhost:1420",
        "distDir": "../dist"
      },
      "package": {
        "productName": "converter-app",
        "version": "0.0.0"
      },
      "tauri": {
        "allowlist": {
          "all": false,
          "dialog": {
            "open": true,
            "message": true
          },
          "path": {
            "all": true 
          },
          "shell": {
            "all": true,
            "execute": true, 
            "sidecar": true, 
            "open": true 
          },
          "fs": {
            "all": true,
            "readFile": true,
            "writeFile": true,
            "readDir": true,
            "copyFile": true,
            "createDir": true,
            "removeDir": true,
            "removeFile": true,
            "renameFile": true,
            "exists": true,
            "scope": ["$APPDATA/**", "*/**"]
          }

        },
        "windows": [
          {
            "title": "converter-app",
            "width": 1000,
            "height": 600
          }
        ],
        "security": {
          "csp": null
        },
        "bundle": {
          "active": true,
          "targets": "all",
          "identifier": "com.tauri.dev",
          "icon": [
            "icons/32x32.png",
            "icons/128x128.png",
            "icons/128x128@2x.png",
            "icons/icon.icns",
            "icons/icon.ico"
          ]
        }
      }
    }

`

Could you post the output of npm run tauri info please?

Try removing src-tauri/target

Looks like you're using Tuari v2?
each version has its own tauri.conf.json..
you're using Tauri's v1 tauri.conf.json structure
good news Tauri has an automated migration to migrate to v2 seamlessly, run:
npm install @tauri-apps/cli@next @tauri-apps/api@next 

then after installing them run:
npm run tauri migrate

more information:
https://v2.tauri.app/start/migrate/from-tauri-1/#automated-migration
